# How to change aspect ratio in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, aspect-ratio

I have 4:3 display and I'm trying to find an option which can give me 21:9 and try to play a game. I found something [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/how-do-i-change-aspect-ratio-windows-10/2b61c273-c0d0-461c-ad6c-1be9edaaafec) (in the last reply) but I think it's outdated now because I don't see that option. In the Radeon center, I found some 16:9 resolutions but not 21:9.

Comment: Usually you can simply configure the display driver to scale the windows size respecting the aspect ratio. Then the display driver will simply add black bars where the game display resolution is too small to fit. Or is it one of those primitive games that are not able to set their own display resolution?

Comment: I tried [this](https://imgur.com/a/hVE7ShU) but it doesn"t have 21:9 resolutions. The game is able to set a resolution but I want to see more view horizontally in the game.

Comment: Leave the monitor in native resolution and set the game resolution to what you want. Also make sure in the section "My digital flat panel" the scaling is set to graphics card and not monitor.

Comment: Unfortunately, the game doesn't have resolution options. It's Cyber Hunter. This game is also available for Android so I try to make this game to think that my display is 21:9.